# Console increment an integer working but calling an identical function "undefined method + for nil class"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Code:

```
#schema..
  t.integer  "shares",             :default => 0
end
```

#model

```
def increment_shares
  shares = shares + 1 #undefined method + for nil class
  save
end

#console

  irb(main):003:0> t.shares
  => 0

  irb(main):004:0> t.shares = t.shares + 1
  => 1

  irb(main):005:0> t.increment_shares
  NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

(Problem should be clear from the code. Writing more text to meet 'quality standards')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `self` to access a model's attributes :

```
def increment_shares
  self.shares = self.shares + 1 
  self.save
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought self called class/static methods?

Comment: Static methods are defined as `def self.myMethod`, thus the confusion :)

Comment: I'm marking correct because this fixes the issue.

Several people have told me to avoid using self in model functions(!)